# Android Studio The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio is showing this error :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA1pK.png)

before that, it shows setup JDK and I did this `File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart`
after that, setup JDK has gone
but it still gives this error :

```
ERROR: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-29\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

my android studio version is 3.5.3

Comment: Attach your error as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this :

```
Android SDK --> SDK Platforms
```

I have unchecked Android 10.0(Q) (related to error) then clicked apply and again I have downloaded that and synced the project.